# Why does code render in code block?

Tags: html, tags

I want to display HTML in a webpage.  I've wrapped in a code block but the last two lines still execute/render.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<pre><code>
div {background: brown;}
div.bluebg {background: blue;}
<div>default brown background</div>
<div class="base">blue background</div>
</code></pre>
```

The last two lines were wrapped in div tags.  I notice stackoverflow strips them out.  I don't want to strip them but modify I guess with `&lt; and &gt;`.  Is there a listing of tags that should be modified to render them in a webpage?  Is there an online program that can convert these to the above syntax?

Comment: i cant parse your question. you need to provide somewhat more information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not think [those tags] mean what you think they mean.

`<pre>` allows you to preserve white space and line feeds. `<code>` allows you to semantically indicate that code is being displayed on your page. Both have some default styles (such as applying a fixed-width font), but neither one does anything to escape `<`, `>`, `&`, or `"`, so any unescaped HTML code you put in between those tags is going to be processed as HTML. You'll have to use `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, and `&quot;`. Here's a page where you can paste in text and have it escaped: http://accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/quick-escape/

Comment: Thanks on the link.  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Just replacing the ```<``` with ```&lt;``` should be enough to get the HTML tag to display as text. You don't have to bother with the ```>``` characters.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;` and `&` with `&amp;` and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the contents of your post I assume you're talking about showing code in Markdown on Stack Overflow.

Don't wrap your code in `<pre>` and `<code>`, just indent it by 4 spaces, like so:

```
div {background: brown;}
div.bluebg {background: blue;}
<div>default brown background</div>
<div class="base">blue background</div>
```

Markdown actually parses HTML (at, least [these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow)) as you can see. Outside of markdown you'd still have to change `<div>` to `&lt;div&gt;` for it to render properly anyway - using code/pree doesn't stop the code from rendering.

Comment: I only want it to display in stackoverflow so others can see the question.  I need to display HTML in a webpage and pre/code isn't working on some tags.  Are you saying I will have to use the less/greater than characters for most tags?